# link user code and ros

Tags: ros, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just started working with the ROS
How can I myself have written a code that would link with ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11638/link-user-code-and-ros/) by [abrsefid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1260/abrsefid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest that you first familiarize yourself further starting from http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/StartGuide and going through a couple of [these tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4